# how variable with data type bool accept store in string bool x="hallo"; no error happen

Tags: c++

It is assumed that the non-zero value is implicitly converted into a Boolean value, which represents the number 1

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  bool x="ahmed";
    cout << x<< "\n";
return 0;
}
```

output:
x is 1

```
using namespace std;
int main() {
  bool x;
  cin>>x;
    cout << x<< "\n";
return 0;
}
```

output:
x is 0

Why, when entering the same text value, was it not considered as a true boolean value, as was the case in the first case?

Comment: `cin>>x;` is a very different operation than `bool x="ahmed";`. Why are you expecting the results being the same??

Comment: hum.. only after writing the answer I realized that your title asks a different question. I was answering the question in your questions body. I suggest to fix the title and if you want to ask why there is no error perhaps open a new question, because its a somewhat different question

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment you are comparing apples with oranges. The two versions of your code do something totally different. While the first is about array to pointer decay and pointer to bool conversion, the other is not about that at all. The second is about formatted extraction from input streams.

Here

```
bool x="ahmed";
```

The `const char[6]` decays to a `const char*` and is subsequently converted to `bool`. Null pointers convert to `false` while others convert to `true`. Hence you get `1` as output.

Here

```
  bool x;
  cin>>x;
```

Things are more involved. You are calling [`std::istream::operator>>(bool&)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) which acts like [`std::num_get::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get), which in case of extracting a `bool` assigns `false` when no `bool` can be extracted. Thats why you see `0` as output.

The relevant part from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get) (emphasize mine):

> If the target sequence is uniquely matched, `v` is set to the corresponding `bool` value. **Otherwise `false` is stored in `v`** and `std::ios_base::failbit` is assigned to `err`. If unique match could not be found before the input ended `(in == end)`, `err |= std::ios_base::eofbit` is executed.

For context, please follow the links, quoting it all and walking trough all the steps in details, would be too much for the scope of this question.

The bottomline is that there is no reason to expect the two versions of your code to yield the same result. Assigning a string literal and extracting input from a stream is completely different stories.